# Change moment locale on runtime globally (make Vue.prototype.moment reactive)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, momentjs

I am importing moment into Vue like so:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022';
Vue.prototype.moment = moment;
```

Then in my `created()`, I setup the languages I want. 
**Bear in mind that this is working with refresh, but not on runtime**.

```
export default new Vue({
   render: h => h(BaseApp), 

   mounted() {

      let supportedLanguages = ['tr', 'etc'];

      supportedLanguages.forEach((val) => {
            moment.locale(val, {
                months: this.$i18n.messages[val]._months_,
                monthsShort: this.$i18n.messages[val]._months_short_,
                monthsParseExact: true,
                weekdays: this.$i18n.messages[val]._weekdays_,
                weekdaysShort: this.$i18n.messages[val]._weekdays_short_,
                weekdaysMin: this.$i18n.messages[val]._weekdays_min_,
                weekdaysParseExact: true,
            });
        })

   },

   methods: {
       changeLocale(lang) {
          this.moment.locale(lang);
       }
   }
})
```

However, in my console if I try `$vm0.moment.locale()` it returns back the correct locale

In all my components, I'm using it in template

`<h1>{{ day.format('ddd') }}</h1>`

The problem is, when I try to change moment's locale, it doesn't change in every component's template. Is there a way to force refresh in all templates. (I tried `$vm.$forceUpdate()` in root)

How can I make moment reactive?

Answer (score 0):

Globally changing the locale on Moment.js does not change the locale on existing moment instances. Even if it did, it would not trigger an update, as Vue is not keeping track of those changes.

I would suggest a different solution using a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin), with a method that sets the locale locally on a moment instance.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        formatDate (moment, format) {
            return moment
                .locale(this.$root.locale)
                .format(format);
        },
    },
});

export default new Vue({
    render: h => h(BaseApp),
    data: {
        locale: 'en'
    },
    methods: {
        changeLocale(locale) {
            this.locale = locale;
        }
    }
 });
```

Your inline template code remains equally readable. However, while fixing your problem, this is also a much more flexible solution that does not care where a moment instance is coming from.

```
<h1>{{ formatDate(day, 'ddd') }}</h1>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Two-way data binding by VueJS. It's not moment problem.

var parent = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  }
})
// $addChild() is an instance method that allows you to
// programatically create a child instance.
var child = parent.$addChild({
  inherit: true,
  data: {
    b: 2
  }
})
console.log(child.a) // -> 1
console.log(child.b) // -> 2
parent.a = 3
console.log(child.a) // -> 3
```

Comment: Well.. How to achieve what I am trying? What is your code chunk explaining here?

Comment: To change every component's template, you should change the parent's data.

Comment: Doesn't this do that `this.moment.locale(lang)` in my root?

Comment: Nope. It doesn't change every component's template.

Comment: So if you don't mind explaining, how to make it reactive?

Comment: The best way is to define an object variable in the Vuex store and use the object on every component. If you change the object value, it will be changed on every component.

Comment: So you are saying use a vuex action for returning a moment instance like as `moment.locale(lang)` and use it in templates. But wouldn't it be non-reactive again?

Comment: Do you know how to use mutation? Action is also fine to modify values.